# Избавиться от null с помощью Optional

Tags: java

Есть вот такая конструкция

```
Integer insertId  = App.officeAccountDao.insertOfficeAccountStep(officeAccountStep).intValue();
OfficeAccountItems officeAccountItems = null;
        if (insertId != null) {
            officeAccountItems = App.officeAccountDao.getOfficeAccountItemById(insertId);
            if (officeAccountItems == null) {
                response.status(404);
                return "";
            }

        }
```

В первой строке происходит добавление в БД и запрос возвращает id добавленной записи. Затем проверяется, равен ли id null или нет, и если не равен, то происходит выборка этой добавленной записи по ее id.
Как избавиться от этих проверок на null, используя Optional? Написал вот так

```
OfficeAccountItems officeAccountItems  = Optional.ofNullable(App.officeAccountDao.insertOfficeAccountStep(officeAccountStep))
                .map(BigInteger::intValue)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(id -> App.officeAccountDao.getOfficeAccountItemById(id))
                .orElse(null);

if (officeAccountItems == null) {
        response.status(404);
        return "";
}
```

Но не уверен что это верно. Оно вроде как работает, и даже работает так как надо, но все таки, по-моему, что-то не так здесь написано

Answer (score 4):

Можно написать просто как-то так:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(App.officeAccountDao.insertOfficeAccountStep(officeAccountStep))
    .map(BigInteger::intValue)
    .map(App.officeAccountDao::getOfficeAccountItemById)
    .orElseGet(() -> {
        response.status(404);
        return "";
    });
```

Использование `filter(Objects::nonNull)` точно лишнее, т.к. `Optional` и так внутри себя всё проверяет.